# Lisp code is not responsive

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, primes, clisp

Spoiler alert: this is the answer to number 7 on Project Euler.

I'm learning Lisp and I was using [compileonline.com](http://www.compileonline.com) to run my code. It was running out of memory on a simple program though, so I switched to a desktop version. However, even that is running out of memory. Can somebody tell me why this is so bad?

In its current form it doesn't hang, but if I change it to:

```
(if (= primecount 10001)
```

it hangs. Even something as small as 1000 hangs.

```
(setq current 3)
(setq primecount 1)
(setq primes (list 2))
(setq isprime "yes")

(loop for x from current do
  (list 
    (setq isprime "yes")
    (loop 
      for prime in primes do 
        (if (= (mod current prime) 0) 
          (list (setq isprime nil) (return)) 
          nil
        )
    )
    (if isprime 
      (list 
        (setq primecount (+ primecount 1)) 
        (setq primes (cons current primes)) 
        (if (= primecount 100) 
          (return) 
          nil
        )
      )
      (setq current (+ current 1))
    )
  )
)

(write-line (write-to-string primes))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TL;DR*: the problem is not with memory, but with speed.

You were very inventive in overcoming your lack of knowledge. :) Actually, we have *`progn`* in Common Lisp, that groups several expressions to be evaluated in order:

```
(defun myprimes-to (n &aux          ;; &aux vars may have init values
                      (current 3)
                      (primecount 1)
                      (isprime t) ; "yes"   ;; t is better 
                      (primes (list 2))
    (loop  ;for x from current do   ;; for a bare loop, just `loop` is enough
      (progn  ;list                 ;; `progn` groups expressions together to be
        (setq isprime t) ; "yes"    ;;    evaluated in order, one after another
        (loop                       ;;      (not even needed here, see comments below)
          for prime in primes do 
            (if (= (mod current prime) 0) 
                (progn  ;list
                  (setq isprime nil) 
                  (return))         ;; exit the loop
                nil))               ;; don't have to have alternative clause
        (if isprime 
            (progn  ;list 
              (incf primecount)  ; (setq primecount (+ primecount 1)) ;; same but shorter
              (setq primes (cons current primes)) 
              (if (= primecount n)  ;; abstract the n as function's argument
                  (return)          ;; exit the loop
                  nil))
            ;; What?? increment your loop var _only_ if it's not prime?
            (setq current (+ current 1)))))
    ;; (write-line (write-to-string primes))
    primes)                         ;; just return them
```

So if `current` is prime, it is retried. Since it was last added into `primes`, it'll now deem itself as non-prime, and the iteration will proceed. The results are correct, but the logic is garbled.

More importantly, there are two major inefficiencies there, *algorithm*-wise: you test by all `primes` so far, and *in reverse*. But, any given number is far more likely to have a *smaller* divisor than a bigger one; so we should test by primes in *ascending* order. And, we can stop when a prime `p` is `p*p > current` – because if `current == a*b` and `a <= b`, then `a*a <= b*a == current`. Stopping early gives enormous speedup, it changes run time complexity from ~ n^2 to, roughly, ~ n^1.5 (in *n* primes produced).

---

Do notice this: your code is *worse* than ~ n^2, algorithmically. It would be ~ n^2, if it were testing by primes in ascending order. -- Why is this important? It provides partial answer to your question: your problems are not with memory, but *speed*. Whatever time it takes your code to finish for *`n=100`*, it will take more than 100x that to get to *`n=1000`* (because 1000/100 == 10, and 10^2 = 100). And it will take it more than another 100x that, to get to the *`n=10000`*. So if the *`n=100`* problem took a second of run time, *`n=1000`* will take 100 seconds (~ 2 minutes), and *`n=10001`* – 200 minutes (more than 3 hours).

We can always take estimates of run-time orders of growth empirically; see [this WP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth).

---

So you need to maintain `primes` in ascending order, and `append` each new prime to their end, in O(1) time. You need to achieve same results as the code line `(setq primes (append primes (list current)))` would achieve; but you can't use this code line because it is O(n) in time, and will drastically slow down the overall program. Same with `(setq primes (reverse (cons current (reverse primes))))`. And we can't maintain `primes` in reverse order because we must test in ascending order, and simply calling `(reverse primes)` for each new `current` is also an O(n) time operation.

The solution is to use  [`rplacd`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rplaca.htm): `(rplacd (last primes) (list current))`. Even this is still not right, because `last` is also an O(n) operation. Instead, you will have to maintain an additional variable, pointing at the primes list's last cons cell, for that, and advance it each time you add a new prime there: `(setq last_cell (cdr last_cell))`.

When you'll run the fixed code, you will find it finishes the 10,000 job in about 0.1 second, and runs at about ~ n^1.4 [run-time orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) in that range.

Comment: but since this is `loop`, we can even just do `loop … when … do …` for the inner `loop`, and for the outer loop, there's no need to `(loop (progn …))`;  we can just do `(loop …)`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor or `prog` instead of loop, with manual `goto`s. ;) :) I just wanted to introduce minimal changes there.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor (I like `prog`, it's a sentimental weakness). :) But also, the bare `loop` is very simple to tweak - here e.g. we'll need to exit early, `(if (> (* prime prime) current) (return))`. It's easy to just add it and not think about the `loop`'s clauses and their interactions... I find the fearless simplicity of the OP code inspiring actually. :)

Comment: @WillNess lol, nice retry of each prime. Thank you for the in depth answer. Still trying to fully understand your runtime analysis, though it mostly makes sense. I was in fact trying to avoid the O(n) insertion and introduced a worse error. I find it interesting no one fixed my too-wide scope of isprime. And no one used let... Also, is there not a better data structure in lisp that gives O(1) insertion.

Comment: Hahaha fearless simplicity :)

Comment: I still think the code is n^2 though. If I'm looking for the nth prime, no check for primality takes more than n operations. Insertion in my code is O(1), so the code boils down to the summation from 1 to n which is O(n^2)

Comment: re "trying to avoid insertion" the 1st focus should be on algorithm, data structures come *2nd* -- your inner loop, `for prime in primes` will never run till its end; will always be cut short - on `(not (zerop (mod current prime)))` or `(> (* prime prime) current)` - this condition you must add into it, to cut it early for primes as well, not only composites. -- where `&aux` works, we don't need `let`. -- re complexity, finish the function and [*measure it*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth). :) (make `primes` &aux var too, as in Reiner's answer).

Comment: @MillieSmith I tested it for n=4,000, n=8,000 and n=10,000, and it runs as fast as Reiner's (the differences are only cosmetic after all), at ~ n^1.4, entirely as expected. Never just test it at one size point, 3 should be enough to see how it performs. -- don't forget to `(compile 'myprimes)` ! :)) -- If you have difficulty arriving at final working code, you can always post a new question with your new code, on SO. :) -- also, (setq isprime t), not "yes", no need for strings.

Answer (score 7):

Can you explain

- what for the variable `X` is and why it is unused?
- what are the calls to `LIST` doing?
- why are you using all these global variables?
- why are you not defining any functions?
- why is the code iterating over all primes?

**Here is refactored and slightly improved version, which is based on your code:**

```
(defun find-primes (n &aux (primes (list 2)) (l-primes primes) (n-primes 1))
  "returns a list of the first n primes"
  (flet ((prime-p (i &aux (limit (isqrt i)))
           "returns T if i is a prime number"
           (loop for prime in primes
                 until (> prime limit)
                 when (zerop (mod i prime))
                 do (return-from prime-p nil))
           t))
    (loop for i from 3
          until (>= n-primes n)
          do (when (prime-p i)
               (setf (cdr l-primes) (list i)
                     l-primes (cdr l-primes))
               (incf n-primes))))
  primes)

(print (find-primes 10000))
```

Features of the above function:

- it keeps a list of primes, increasing
- it keeps a reference to the last *cons* of the list of primes, to add to the end of a list efficiently
- it has a predicate sub-function `prime-p` which returns `T` if a number is a prime
- the predicate uses the function `isqrt` to limit the numbers to search

With a check for `N` and a local macro for the push to the end it looks like this:

```
(defun find-primes (n &aux (primes (list 2)) (l-primes primes) (n-primes 1))
  "returns a list of the first n primes"
  (check-type n (integer 1))
  (flet ((prime-p (i &aux (limit (isqrt i)))
           "returns T if i is a prime number"
           (loop for prime in primes
                 until (> prime limit)
                 when (zerop (mod i prime))
                 do (return-from prime-p nil))
           t))
    (macrolet ((push-last (obj place)
                 `(setf (cdr ,place) (list ,obj)
                        ,place (cdr ,place))))
      (loop for i from 3
            until (>= n-primes n)
            do (when (prime-p i)
                 (push-last i l-primes)
                 (incf n-primes)))))
  primes)
```

Let's try it:

```
CL-USER 3 > (time (find-primes 10000))
Timing the evaluation of (FIND-PRIMES 10000)

User time    =        0.052
System time  =        0.000
Elapsed time =        0.044
Allocation   = 292192 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. 1. to loop until a condition 2. Allowing me to run multiple lines of code 3. Lack of knowledge 4. I felt like keeping it simple for this first program 5. Because the Euler problem is to find the 10001st prime.

Comment: @Millie Smith: 1) iteration is over a variable from start to end. You don't do that. You are doing something totally strange. You are not using the declared iteration variable at all and you increase the start in every iteration. 2) PROGN 5) why do you need to test all the primes of the list then?

Comment: @rainierjoswig Then how do I loop for the 10001st prime? 2. Thanks, I'll take a look. 5. Because a composite number has to be divisible by one of the primes below it. It was supposed to optimize the solution.

Comment: @Millie Smith: 1) that's not the question. The question is why you introduce `X`, but actually iterate over `current`. 5) True, but you don't need to look at all of those.

Comment: Hmm I will be trying this code as soon as I get internet. I am intrigued by your speed results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is somewhat buggy. 
`list` function is there to construct and return a list, it shouldn't enforce an evaluation order.  You want `progn` to execute a bunch of forms as one, and it return the value of its last form.

I rewrote it a bit:

```
(defvar current)
(setf current 3)
(defvar primecount)
(setf primecount 1)
(defvar primes)
(setf primes (list 2))
(defvar isprime)

(loop for x from current do
  (setq isprime t)
  (loop 
    for prime in primes do 
      (when (zerop (mod current prime))
        (setq isprime nil) (return)))
  (if isprime 
      (progn 
        (incf primecount)
        (push current primes)
        (when (= primecount 10001) 
          (return)))
      (incf current)))
(write-line (write-to-string primes))
```

I hazard a guess that your code uses a lot of memory because you use lists as your data structure, and as they get huge, the garbage collector struggles with creation and destruction of lists.

Your program works in my SBCL for 10001 like this (wrapped in a do-stuff function):

```
CL-USER> (time (do-stuff))
Evaluation took:
  13.486 seconds of real time
  13.438000 seconds of total run time (13.437000 user, 0.001000 system)
  99.64% CPU
  40,470,003,369 processor cycles
  1,674,208 bytes consed

CL-USER> (room)
Dynamic space usage is:   134,466,112 bytes.
Read-only space usage is:      5,856 bytes.
Static space usage is:         4,032 bytes.
Control stack usage is:        8,808 bytes.
Binding stack usage is:        1,056 bytes.
Control and binding stack usage is for the current thread only.
Garbage collection is currently enabled.

Breakdown for dynamic space:
  45,803,376 bytes for   569,191 instance objects.
  22,831,488 bytes for 1,426,968 cons objects.
  16,472,576 bytes for    16,135 code objects.
  15,746,176 bytes for   130,439 simple-vector objects.
  13,794,096 bytes for    36,381 simple-character-string objects.
  19,850,400 bytes for   440,297 other objects.
  134,498,112 bytes for 2,619,411 dynamic objects (space total.)
```

Comment: actually, only one list of primes is created, by consing on top, so 1,000 or 10,000 primes, it is still a very small space usage.

Comment: there's no reason for `loop … do (when test form…)`;  `loop … when test do form…` is fine.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor you're totally right; i just wanted to replace the original (if cond (progn ...) nil) form at the time.